# Cytoscape.js: edge labeling on two sides

Tags: cytoscape.js, edges, labeling

Is it possible in Cytoscape.js to double-label an edge, i.e. display two strings on the two ends, next to the connected nodes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just set the source and target labels in your stylesheet : http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/labels